# Enable/disable of textbox on option selected from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is that the text box is only accessible if a certain option is picked from the drop down menu and I have an html form as below:

```
 <tr>
 <td>a.&nbsp;Did any  of your staff participate in training or orientation sessions related to any aspect of social performance management, during the reporting year? </td>
 <td >
 <p>
   <select name="mfi_4_a_i">
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option>No</option>
     <option>No, but planning in future</option>
   </select>
 </p>
 <p>if not,and not planning please explain why not </p>
 <input type="text" name="mfi_4_a_ii" id="sdd" />
 </tr>
```

Now when a user selects the option No, but planning in future then the text box must be enabled otherwise the textbox must be disabled.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Duplicate [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255969/how-to-make-a-checkbox-enable-and-disable-a-text-box-in-multiple-cases) by same user

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should call the javascript function for this.

```
<select id="mfi_4_a_i" name="mfi_4_a_i" onChange="changetextbox();">
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
    <option>No, but planning in future</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="mfi_4_a_ii" id="sdd" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function changetextbox()
{
    if (document.getElementById("mfi_4_a_i").value === "noy") {
        document.getElementById("sdd").disable='true';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sdd").disable='false';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: .disable is not a valid property/attribute
document.getElementById("sdd").disable='true';
should actually be
document.getElementById("sdd").disabled='true';

then false is not a valid value for "disabled"   make it  "" empty instead.

Comment: What is "noy" and how it represent the last option

Answer (score 8):

For me the `document.getElementById("sdd").disabled='false'` did not work so I used

`document.getElementById("sdd").disabled='';`

```
if (document.getElementById("mfi_4_a_i").value === "noy") {
    document.getElementById("sdd").disabled='true';
} else {
    document.getElementById("sdd").disabled='';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just corrections...
removal of ;  , === , noy , 'true' #no quotes

```
onChange="changetextbox();"
if (document.getElementById("mfi_4_a_i").value == "no") {
document.getElementById("sdd").disabled=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without doing a roundtrip to the server, you'll have to do that with javascript

Comment: can u tell me in detail or can u give me a link or some tips to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("the_id").disabled='';` works for me. works, much like `style.display`