# enabling a textbox on the selectionof a option in the drop down menu in multiple cases

Tags: php, html

What I want is that the text box is only accessible if a certain option is picked from the drop down menu and i have a html form as below:

a. Did any  of your staff participate in training or orientation sessions related to any aspect of social performance management, during the reporting year?

Please choose one.
                                                                Yes
                                                                No
                                                                No, but planning in future

if not,and not planning please explain why not?

```
                                                        <input type="text" name="mfi_4_a_ii" class="init" disabled="disabled"/>
                                                  </tr>
```

Now when the option No, but planning in future is selected then the textbox must be enabled.This type of dropdown menu has been used many times in this form so i have to enable the textbox in another similar case too so how a single function can be written to do this.Help me out guys.

Comment: Did you get answer here as you accedpted that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258182/enable-disable-of-textbox-on-option-selected-from-drop-down-menu

Answer (score 0):

You should explain it further as I'm not able to understand it!
But you can try out jquery for help!
And as far as I get it you should try out this link...
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/

Just make some changes...
Hope it worked!