# PHP: Disable Enable text box on the basis of dropdown

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. i am trying to create some html code within a php function as below.

---

```
$str .="</div>
                <div class='cls_setpadding'>
                    <form method='get' action='homepage.php'>
                    <div class='cls_caller_options'>
                        <select name='test'>
                            <option value='allcaller'>".getResourceStrings('msg_allcaller',$lng)."</option>
                            <option value='specialcaller'>".getResourceStrings('msg_splcaller',$lng)."</option>
                        </select><br />
                    </div>
                    <div class='cls_msg_splcaller'>";
        $str .=      getResourceStrings('msg_spcallaer',$lng);          
        $str .="    </div>
                    <div style='padding-top:2%'></div>
                    <div class='cls_search_box'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='function' value='Buysuccess' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='vcode' value='".$vcode."' />";
                    if($testmsisdnheader != ""){
                        $msisdn_header = getheader();
                        $str .="<input type='hidden' name='".$msisdn_header."' value='".$msisdn."' />";
                    }

        $str .="    <input type='text' onkeydown='return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
                    || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false) 
                    || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
                    || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9) 
                    || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
                    || (event.keyCode==46) )' name='cbsmsisdn' maxlength='12' disabled='true'/><br />
                    <div style='padding-top:1%'></div>
                    <input type='submit' value='Submit' /><br />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>";
```

---

Now I want to enable/disable the text box on the basis of value selected in drop down.

Here i like to put a condition where if the option value equals 'allcaller' the text box should be disabled which is actually happening.
But I want to enable the same text box in case option value equals to 'specialcaller'.

I wasn't able to enable the text box on the basis of value selected in drop down.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks! 
Bobby.

Comment: Refer this Link...

[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258182/enable-disable-of-textbox-on-option-selected-from-drop-down-menu)


It will help..

Comment: I have added disabled='true'.  If I remove this the text box becomes editable. However, what I want is to put a condition or any other way to decide what value has been chose. On the basis of that value, I will construct the string with parameter disabled='true'.

If there is any other way to do this, I'm perfectly okay with it.  But, I do not want to use java script unless there is no other option to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two possible solutions for you.

1. As you have mentioned in comment that you dont want to use java script, as its a WAP Portal, but their is no other way to do this without using javascript. I can recommend you a one way where you can ask user to submit his drop down result. And on the basis of that result you can enable or disable you text box on next page.
2. Otherwise go for javascript.