# How to I disable the textbox by default and enable it later?

Tags: php, javascript, html

How to I disable the textbox by default and let the user enable it via checkbox?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sccb" name="science" value="science">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sccb').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
    $('#cns').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
    $("#cns").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="cns" name="coornamescience" disabled="disabled" size="30"></input>
```

Comment: With some JavaScript code, but I don't see any [evidence of effort or independent research.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable/disable of textbox on option selected from drop down menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258182/enable-disable-of-textbox-on-option-selected-from-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 3):

use `disabled="disabled"` for textbox and then use `JS/jQuery` to enabled on click

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/jaCmE/

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" disabled="disabled" id="mytextbox">
</textarea>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
```

And then use `Javascript/jQuery` like this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
    $('#mytextbox').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
    $("#mytextbox").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: You never re-disable the text box when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @icktoofay User never asked for this...and it is not in the initial requirement..Also the question lags any RESEARCH from the questionnaire..so it is just a basic brick not the actual work..he can continue his work from here

Comment: What use is a checkbox that you can only ever enable? If it's supposed to be done only once, it's supposed to be, I don't know, a *button*? Perhaps one that disables itself after it's been clicked once?

Comment: @icktoofay ok-2 no more fighting lol..I updated my answer :)

Comment: What if I want the checkbox to control multiple textbox?

Comment: @Pey you can easily do it too

Comment: @Pey Check my updated fiddle

Comment: I tried, it doesn't works in my case. I've updated my question with my codes.

Comment: @Pey its working ...check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NeHyM/

Comment: The *disabled* attribute is boolean, no value is required in HTML. The second argument for [setAttribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082) is a string, not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, first disable the text box. Then add a `change` event handler to the check box. In it, set the disabled state of the text box to the opposite of the checked status.

Comment: [**Try it.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WHSc2/embedded/result,html,js/)

Answer (score 0):

You can you javascript to disable the textbox on page load, then add an event to the checkbox to re-enable the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disenable(e) {
  e[0].disabled = e[1].checked ? "" : "disabled"
}
</script>
<form action="">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled"><br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="disenable(this.form)">Click me
</form>
```

Here e is the form, e[0] is the first input (the textbox) and e[1] is the second input (the checkbox).
When the checkbox changes it calls disenable passing the form as input, the function erases or sets the textbox's disabled argument besed on it's checked status.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to target the checkbox and if the checkbox is enabled then the textbox is disabled and vice versa. 
Html:

```
<form action="">
<input type="text" name="box" id="mytext" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="mycheckbox" />
</form>
```

Js:

```
    $(function(){
    //Disable the textbox
   var textbox = $('#mytext');
   textbox.attr("disabled","disabled");

    $('#mycheckbox').change(function(){
       //Enable input
        if(textbox.attr('disabled')){
           $('#mytext').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else {
            textbox.attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
    });

});
```

Here's the illustration on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X5TVx/

Answer (score 0):

As icktoofay said, leave it enabled in the markup, then disable it using script.

```
<input type="text" id="i0">
<label for="cb0"><input id="cb0" type="checkbox">Check to enable</label>

<script>
  document.getElementById('i0').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('cb0').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('i0').disabled = !this.checked;
  };
</script>
```