# Toggle element on selection from dropdown menu in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap `3.0` for Ruby on Rails `4.2.5`, and I need to make it so that in this form when the user selects the option "No" from the drop down menu, the next text field is shown to them, otherwise, the text field remains hidden.  I've found a similar question with this solution, but I couldn't implement it with the Bootstrap form, this is my attempt at it :

Dropdown Input: 
  `<%= f.select :answer, [["Yes", 1], ["No", 0]], label: "Do you wish to bla bla? ", class: "selectpicker", Id: "selectpicker" %>`

Toggled Input (should show when "No" is picked) :
  `<%= f.text_area :explain , label: "Please explain why not", Id: "sdd"%>`

Javascript:  `

```
 ("selectpicker").change(function changetextbox());
 function changetextbox()
{
    if (document.getElementById("selectpicker").value === 0 ) {
        document.getElementById("sdd").disable='true';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sdd").disable='false';
    }
}
```

`

I tried changing `value === 0` to `value == 0` and the `0` to `No`, but it still doesn't work.

They're in my code in this order, but I'm not sure how this should work with the bootstrap form tags. Thanks in advance.

*Reference* : This is the question from which i got this code
[Enable/disable of textbox on option selected from drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258182/enable-disable-of-textbox-on-option-selected-from-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectpicker', changetextbox);

function changetextbox() {
  if (document.getElementById("selectpicker").value === '0') {
    document.getElementById("sdd").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sdd").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

1. You forgot `$` and there is no `selectpicker` selector, you have to use class or ID like `.selectpicker` or `#selectpicker` when you use jQuery (depends on your HTML).
2. There is no `disable`, you have to use `disabled` and you can't use quotation marks for `true` and `false`.
3. You can't use `.change(function changetextbox())`, just use `$(document).on('change', '#selectpicker', changetextbox)`.
4. `0` must be in quotation marks.
5. I assume your textarea is only disabled (not hidden by CSS).

### [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/ezvxpR)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code,

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectbox" name="mfi_4_a_i">
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="mfi_4_a_ii" id="sdd" />
```

**JS**

```
$("#selectbox").change(function() {
     changetextbox();
});

function changetextbox(){
    if (document.getElementById("selectbox").value === '0') {
        document.getElementById("sdd").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sdd").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/8mag64es/6/

And if you want more cleaner jquery way, you can update your **JS** code as below,

```
var selectbox = $("#selectbox"),
    textbox = $("#sdd");  

selectbox.change(function() {
     changetextbox();
});

function changetextbox(){
    if (selectbox.val() === '0') {
        textbox.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        textbox.prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8mag64es/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<select id="selectbox" name="mfi_4_a_i">
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="sdd" disabled="true" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var $sdd = $('#sdd');
    $('#selectbox').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val()==='0'){
        $sdd.prop("disabled", false);
    }else{
        $sdd.prop("disabled", true);
    }
  })
});
```

Also check https://jsfiddle.net/k5gy365k/3/